# When I Deploy my gwt application on tomcat and run it in IE all the images from the resource bundle appear on the screen

Tags: image, internet-explorer, gwt, tomcat

Hi I am developing a project where I need to produce a time line sort of a thing where in I need to place images dynamically in a horizontal line depending on the condition. The image instance would differ based on the condition from the data base and the number of instances also would differ. I used an absolute panel to do so and placed the images at a difference of 40 between the horizontal axis keeping the y-axis constant. The images come from a class which  extends Client Bundle as follows.

```
  public interface TimeLineWidgetResources extends ClientBundle {

TimeLineWidgetResources INSTANCE = GWT
        .create(TimeLineWidgetResources.class);

@Source("application-connection-point_big.png")
ImageResource getApplicationConnectionPointImage();

@Source("business-connection-point_big.png")
ImageResource getBusinessConnectionPointImage();

@Source("monitor_small.png")
ImageResource getMonitorImage();
```

}

I have placed only 3 here but in my resource file i have almost 15 images.
The time line looked perfect on the jetty server in IE, Chrome and Safari. But when i create a war and deploy it in tomcat it looks perfect in Chrome and safari but all the images come and get displayed on the screen in IE. if i create 5 instances of it then it is creating 5*15 = 75 instances of those images. Can anybody help me with this. What am I doing wrong here? Let me post the absolute panel code as well here.

```
  /** The method to build Time Line using an absolute Panel */

public void buildNewTimeLine(GWTTimeLine timeLine) {
    absolutePanel.setPixelSize((Window.getClientWidth() * 3) / 4, 200);
    absolutePanel.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
    String startDate = timeLine.getStartDate();
    String endDate = timeLine.getEndDate();
    List<GWTTimeLineComponent> timeLineComponents = new ArrayList<GWTTimeLineComponent>();
    timeLineComponents = timeLine.getComponents();
    buildTimeLineEvents(timeLineComponents);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < timeLineComponents.size(); i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            Image startImage = new Image();
            startImage
                    .setUrl(resources.getVerticalLineImage().getSafeUri());
            absolutePanel.add(startImage, 48, 70);

        }

        if (i == (timeLineComponents.size() - 1)) {
            Image continueImage = new Image();
            continueImage
                    .setUrl(resources.getLineArrowImage().getSafeUri());
            absolutePanel.add(continueImage, horizontalImageXAxis + 80, 70);

        }

        GWTTimeLineComponent timeLineComponent = new GWTTimeLineComponent();
        timeLineComponent = timeLineComponents.get(i);
        String icon = timeLineComponent.getIcon();
        int id = timeLineComponent.getId();
        String logicalId = timeLineComponent.getLogicalId();
        List<GWTTimeLineEvent> timeLineEvents = new ArrayList<GWTTimeLineEvent>();
        timeLineEvents = timeLineComponent.getEvents();

        if (icon.startsWith("infor.engine.monitor")) {

            if (isAbove == true) {
                isAbove = false;
                isBelow = true;
                Image monitorImage = new Image();
                monitorImage.setUrl(resources.getMonitorImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                monitorImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "up";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        monitorImage, id, logicalId);
            }

            else if (isBelow == true) {
                isAbove = true;
                isBelow = false;
                Image monitorImage = new Image();
                monitorImage.setUrl(resources.getMonitorImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                monitorImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "down";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        monitorImage, id, logicalId);

            }

        } else if (icon.startsWith("infor.database")) {

            if (isAbove == true) {
                isAbove = false;
                isBelow = true;
                Image databaseImage = new Image();
                databaseImage.setUrl(resources
                        .getDatabaseConnectionPointImage().getSafeUri());
                databaseImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "up";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        databaseImage, id, logicalId);

            }

            else if (isBelow == true) {
                isAbove = true;
                isBelow = false;
                Image databaseImage = new Image();
                databaseImage.setUrl(resources
                        .getDatabaseConnectionPointImage().getSafeUri());
                databaseImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());

                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "down";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        databaseImage, id, logicalId);

            }

        } else if (icon.startsWith("infor.jms")) {

            if (isAbove == true) {
                isAbove = false;
                isBelow = true;
                Image jmsImage = new Image();
                jmsImage.setUrl(resources.getJmsQueueConnectionPointImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                jmsImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "up";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        jmsImage, id, logicalId);
            }

            else if (isBelow == true) {
                isAbove = true;
                isBelow = false;
                Image jmsImage = new Image();
                jmsImage.setUrl(resources.getJmsQueueConnectionPointImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                jmsImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "down";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        jmsImage, id, logicalId);
            }

        } else if (icon.startsWith("infor.ws")) {

            if (isAbove == true) {
                isAbove = false;
                isBelow = true;
                Image webServiceImage = new Image();
                webServiceImage.setUrl(resources
                        .getWebServiceConnectionPointImage().getSafeUri());
                webServiceImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "up";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        webServiceImage, id, logicalId);

            }

            else if (isBelow == true) {
                isAbove = true;
                isBelow = false;
                Image webServiceImage = new Image();
                webServiceImage.setUrl(resources
                        .getWebServiceConnectionPointImage().getSafeUri());
                webServiceImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "down";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        webServiceImage, id, logicalId);

            }

        } else if (icon.startsWith("infor.sap")) {

            if (isAbove == true) {
                isAbove = false;
                isBelow = true;
                Image sapImage = new Image();
                sapImage.setUrl(resources.getBusinessConnectionPointImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                sapImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "up";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        sapImage, id, logicalId);

            }

            else if (isBelow == true) {
                isAbove = true;
                isBelow = false;
                Image sapImage = new Image();
                sapImage.setUrl(resources.getBusinessConnectionPointImage()
                        .getSafeUri());
                sapImage.setTitle(timeLineComponent.getLogicalId());
                String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow = "down";
                buildTimeLineComponents(downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
                        sapImage, id, logicalId);

            }

        }

        else if (icon.startsWith("infor.bod")) {
            Image horizontalLine = new Image();
            horizontalLine.setUrl(resources.getHorizontalLineImage()
                    .getSafeUri());

            Image bodImage = new Image();
            bodImage.setUrl(resources.getBodImage().getSafeUri());
            addBodImageClickHandlers(bodImage,
                    searchEvent.getSelectedMessageId());
            bodImageXAxis = horizontalImageXAxis + 40;
            horizontalImageXAxis = horizontalImageXAxis + 20;
            bodImageYAxis = 65;
            absolutePanel.add(bodImage, bodImageXAxis, bodImageYAxis);
        }
    }

}

/** The method to build Time Line components */

public void buildTimeLineComponents(String downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow,
        Image connectionPointImage, int id, String logicalId) {

    Image horizontalLine = new Image();
    horizontalLine.setUrl(resources.getHorizontalLineImage().getSafeUri());
    Image arrow = new Image();
    if (downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow.equals("down")) {
        arrow.setUrl(resources.getDownArrowImage().getSafeUri());
        connectionPointImageYAxis = 95;
        arrowImageYAxis = 72;
    }

    if (downOrUpOrBiDirectionalArrow.equals("up")) {
        arrow.setUrl(resources.getUpArrowImage().getSafeUri());
        connectionPointImageYAxis = 10;
        arrowImageYAxis = 46;
    }
    addConnectionPointImageClickHandlers(connectionPointImage, id,
            logicalId);
    horizontalImageXAxis = horizontalImageXAxis + widthBetweenTImages;
    absolutePanel.add(horizontalLine, horizontalImageXAxis,
            horizontalImageYAxis);
    connectionPointImageXAxis = horizontalImageXAxis + 7;
    arrowImageXAxis = horizontalImageXAxis + 15;
    absolutePanel.add(connectionPointImage, connectionPointImageXAxis,
            connectionPointImageYAxis);
    absolutePanel.add(arrow, arrowImageXAxis, arrowImageYAxis);

}
```

Please Help.

Comment: You are referring to `resources` in all of your `.setUrl` calls; are you setting this equal to `TimeLineWidgetResources.INSTANCE`?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

In IE 6-7 (or equivalent document modes in IE8+), `getSafeUri()` returns the URL of a composite image (aka sprited image), as explained in the Javadoc: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/ImageResource.html#getSafeUri%28%29

Use [`Image#setResource`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#setResource%28com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource%29) instead of `Image#setUrl`.

Comment: It did not work for me even when I used Image.setResource instead of Image.setUrl. I used it as follows: monitorImage.setResource(resources.getMonitorImage()); What else am i doing wrong? Please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by _did not work_ ? same issue ? not updating ? not displaying anything ?

Comment: The image still appears to be like sprite... and i still get a lot of instances of all the images......

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IE8 and higher which was set to compatibility mode.
To ensure your sprites being rendered correctly in IE set it to IE8 mode by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` to the header section of your project html.